# What is the meaning of "Unfortunately, the process android.process.media has stopped."

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

[image]

It keeps popping up when I start using the phone, shortly after it has booted. The phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (SM-N900), running Android-5.0

I flashed the phone and installed a fresh copy of the stock Android-5.0 the one I got it with (OTA update). What could be wrong with it. I need an interpretation of this error message. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the error message in `logcat` then you see more details.

Answer (score 0):

android.process.media appears to be, as the name suggests, "Media Storage" crashing. Clearing "Media Storage" cache doesn't work when *another* app is causing it to crash -- and this app is almost always "Download Manager". Clearing the cache of both apps fixes it:

- Settings -> Application Manager -> All apps.
- Find "Download manager", and select "clear cache".
- Find "Media Storage", and select "clear cache".

Some odd websites suggest disabling "Media Storage". Well of course it will get rid of the errors... But you won't even be able to access the pictures you took from the Samsung "Gallery" app, or even take photos or screenshots.

Source: I had this problem again with my good old Note 3. Writing this to help others because most websites don't help much.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While your answer might help solving the issue behind (and probably indeed does), OP was asking for background of the meaning: Why are your actions needed? How do they solve the issue? Moreover, what **IS** the underlying issue? It would be great if you could **[edit]** your answer and include those details. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

android.process.media is a common issue which can occur anytime and is caused mainly because of two applications, the Download Manager and the Media Storage.

try the following

1. Go to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications and make sure to look under the ‘all’ tab. Scroll down and find Google Services Framework and clear the cache and data for this one.
2. After doing that, scroll down and find Google Play. Tap on it and clear cache+data for this one too.
3. Now press the back button and choose Google Services Framework from all apps > Force stop > Clear cache > OK
4. Now open Google Play from you app drawer and when given an error, click OK.
5. Turn off your device by holding the power button and clicking on Shut down/ Reboot

Comment: What has `android.process.media` to do with Google Services Framework or Play Services? The former is an AOSP service which is always there even if device has no Google Services.

Comment: I just consider my own experience and some tips that I know. I suggested clearing cache /data, it can be a relevant solution, one of those. also, there are such suggestions as uninstall CCCleaner lol, but I don't know if OP has one.