# Unfortunately, the process android.process.media has stopped

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, system-error, samsung-galaxy-note-3

There are frequent messages like this on a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Android 5.0. Factory reset didn't help. Can anybody suggest a solution? I have studied [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224760/202005) by the way.

> Unfortunately, the process android.process.media has stopped.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does the error directly occur after factory reset or did you already install other apps? Because this error can be caused by corrupt media files (images, audio, video,...).

Comment: @Robert I have done factory reset multiple times and as far as I remember, it starts after a while. So I guess it is observed after installing some app.

Comment: Note that there are several security vulnerabilities known that attack the media store scanner (which should be the process that is affected in your case) using modified files. The attacker can get root access by this, so be careful what you do with such an old phone...

Comment: @Robert Thanks. That was a great warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Robert commented:

> Note that there are several security vulnerabilities known that attack the media store scanner (which should be the process that is affected in your case) using modified files. The attacker can get root access by this, so be careful what you do with such an old phone...

Following the above comment, I did a factory reset and installed a few trusted apps only. The error was resolved and didn't happen again.